# Use heatmaply with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, heatmaply

I just discovered heatmaply and I was trying to use produced a grouped heatmap. I checked the documentation and noticed the "heatmap_layers" option, which can be used to add ggplot code to the heatmap, so I figured a working solution:

```
df <- mtcars %>%
    select(-vs) %>%
    t()

group_names <- mtcars %>%
    mutate(vs = ifelse(vs == 0, "v-shaped", "straight"))

group_names[] <- as.character(group_names$vs)

group_names <- group_names %>%
    select(-vs) %>%
    t()
heatmaply(df,
    scale = "row",
    heatmap_layers = facet_grid(cols = vars({as.vector(group_names)})
    )
)
```

This separates the two categories "straight" and "v-shaped" as expected. The problem is the dendrogram produced doesn't match the heatmap and also overlaps with the strip element produced by ggplot. I tried with the option "dendrogram_layers" but can't find a solution.

[image]